# What is the type for color in Chakra UI when creating an interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, chakra-ui

I'm not sure what to enter for color or background. Property.color doesn't exist. There must be something that represents all these color options that can be normally seen. I've entered any right now to prevent error but that doesn't give me type hinting for colors.

```
import {
  BackgroundProps,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  ColorProps,
  Colors,
  HStack,
  Icon,
  ResponsiveValue,
  Text,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { HiFolder } from "react-icons/hi";
import { MdKeyboardArrowRight } from "react-icons/md";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
  color: ResponsiveValue<any>;
  //   backgroundColor: BackgroundProps;
}

function DashboardLinkSectionCard({ children, color }: Props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Card
        // maxW={"ms"}
        maxH={"20"}
        color={color}
        // backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
      >
        <CardBody>
          <HStack gap={2}>
            <Icon as={HiFolder} boxSize={6} />
            <Text>{children}</Text>
            <Icon as={MdKeyboardArrowRight} boxSize={6} />
          </HStack>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}

export default DashboardLinkSectionCard;
```

This is the suggestions I would normally get.

[image]

One possible solution is, I copy all the colors and make a custom type like this. Surely there must be a better way.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use the `ChakraProps` interface to achieve what you want. It contains a `color` attribute that enumerates all the values allowed by Chakra. This is also applicable to the `backgroundColor` prop:

```
import { ChakraProps } from '@chakra-ui/react';

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
  color: ChakraProps['color'];
  backgroundColor: ChakraProps['backgroundColor'];
}
```

Actually, the `ChakraProps` interface extends `SystemProps` which itself extends `ColorProps` and `BackgroundProps` (that you already imported). So you could do this as an alternative option:

```
import { BackgroundProps, ColorProps } from '@chakra-ui/react';

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
  color: ColorProps['color'];
  backgroundColor: BackgroundProps['backgroundColor'];
}
```